# Why does Spark/Scala compiler fail to find toDF on RDD[Map[Int, Int]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why does the following end up with an error?

```
scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).map(x => (Map(x  -> 0), 0))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int], Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[20] at map at <console>:27

scala> rdd.toDF
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: map<int,int>, _2: int]

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).map(x => Map(x  -> 0))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = MapPartitionsRDD[23] at map at <console>:27

scala> rdd.toDF
<console>:30: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]]
              rdd.toDF
```

So what exactly is happening here, toDF can convert RDD of type `(scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int], Int)` to DataFrame but not of type `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]`. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the same reason why you cannot use

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(1 to 10).map(x => Map(x  -> 0))
```

If you take a look at the `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext` source you'll find two different implementations of the `createDataFrame` method:

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A]): DataFrame
```

and

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](data: Seq[A]): DataFrame
```

As you can see both require `A` to be a subclass of `Product`. When you call `toDF` on a `RDD[(Map[Int,Int], Int)]` it works because `Tuple2` is indeed a `Product`. `Map[Int,Int]` by itself is not hence the error.

You can make it work by wrapping `Map` with `Tuple1`:

```
sc.parallelize(1 to 10).map(x => Tuple1(Map(x  -> 0))).toDF
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically because there is no implicit to create a DataFrame for a Map inside an RDD.

In you first example you are returning a Tuple, which is a Product for which there is an implicit conversion.

[rddToDataFrameHolder[A <: Product : TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A])](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/642c43c81c835139e3f35dfd6a215d668a474203/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L46)

In the second example you use have a Map in your RDD, for which there is no implicit conversion.