# value toDF is not a member org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    //require spark sql environment
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val df1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5).map(i => (i, i * 2)).toDF("single", "double")
    sc.stop()
  }
```

I have written "import sqlContext.implicits._";
However it still does not work. It is right in spark-shell. 
Why it is not right in this situation?
I have see many other methods to translate rdd to data frame,
but most of my code has been written as toDF().
How to do to make toDF work?
the error:

```
Error:(25, 55) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
val df1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5).map(i => (i, i * 2)).toDF("single", "double")
                                                  ^
```

Comment: That is interesting, I cannot recreate this, and your code runs fine here, your call to `sqlContext` is correct; do you want to try add `import org.apache.spark.sql._` ? Maybe it is your IDE not responding properly? If you are using Eclipse you might need to do a sbt eclipse or something to include the library in the debugger.

Comment: What's your build configuration ? Spark's version ?

Comment: @GameOfThrows I believe the OP is using a version of spark <= 1.3

Comment: would you care sharing the relevant dependencies part of your build file ? sbt or maven ?

Comment: @eliasah ofc that, face palm moment.

Comment: Could be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522942/why-does-spark-scala-compiler-fail-to-find-todf-on-rddmapint-int) issue?

Comment: No it's not the case.

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is with your stack version. I am able to execute the same code with my configurations. Can you please share your Scala version? It is working fine with 2.10.x scala version.

Comment: spark-1.6.1 scala 2.11.8

Comment: Thx, I change to scala 2.10.x and it works fine.

Comment: I used your code with scala 2.11 and it worked fine, which version of jvm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

toDF() has been added in Spark version 1.3, 
you must be using an older version (lesser than 1.3) of Spark, that's why you are getting this error. 
 To resolve this, use Spark version 1.3 or above.